# grails error: grails.validation.Validateable is not an annotation in @grails.validation.Validateable

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-3.1

Working through upgrading from grails 2.2.5 to 3.1 and we have an interesting error.  How do we resolve this?

```
class grails.validation.Validateable is not an annotation in @grails.validation.Validateable
 @ line 17, column 1.
   @Validateable
   ^
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is that in Grails 2.x the 'Validateable' was applied using an annotation

```
@Validateable
class ApiCatalogCommand {}
```

In grails 3.x, it is now an interface:

```
class ApiCatalogCommand implements Validateable {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a pity though - seems like a step backwards.

Comment: @JoeyHolloway nope, you define constraints in `static constraints = { ... }` block of the class. Just like with the domain objects

Comment: I know this is years later, so I'm unsure of what value it may be, but I wanted to clarify that Validateable is now a trait, not an interface. I only say that because traits are much different than interfaces.